# ER-Diagram: Entity with multivalued attribute missing primary key

Tags: entity-relationship

Here is an example: the entity "treatment" is missing a primary key. Is this just an error or is it possible to convert this to a relational data model?

[ER-Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vKHV.png)

Comment: How do you know that treatment entity is missing a PK?

Comment: Because of the missing underscore?

Comment: If you have a person's name down as PK, then you have pretty big problems with this ERD!